# How does one determine when a comedian is also a humorist?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

Wikipedia's [list of humorists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_humorists) are categorised as people who write or perform humorous material, but the article also states:

> A humorist is usually distinct from a [stand-up comedian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-up_comedian).

Woody Allen and George Carlin are on this list—clearly, a stand-up comedian can also be a humorist.

There are various [distinctions on the web](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-humorist.htm).

> Humorists typically receive higher pay.

This is ambiguous; one's salary does not define their job.

> A humorist’s job is to make people laugh at important things.

Whilst I find this distinction more satisfactory, it's still open to debate: the importance of material is subjective.

How does one determine when a comedian is also a humorist?

Comment: Sounds like "humorists" are more pretentious than comedians. ("Humorist" is also clearly a broader term, as that article mentions: "Some humorists write books, columns, essays, and articles"—sombody can do these and be a "humorist" without ever doing stand-up comedy.) It is confusing to me also how someone could be a comedian without being a humorist. Hope you get some good answers!

Comment: Macmillan Dictionary has for *humorist*: "someone who writes in a clever and funny way about real people and events, often for newspapers"

Comment: This is a question involving specialist usages. I can find overlapping definitions. I'd say that in general (outside the profession) usage, a comedian virtually needs a live audience, and 'humourist' is a higher-register term.

Comment: I doubt you're going to find a definitive answer to this. It's subjective. Different people will have different opinions, so it's going to depend on exactly who you're asking. Especially if you're writing for an audience that differentiates between the two.

Comment: Comedians tell their jokes. Humorists write them. 'Comedian' is a much more common term nowadays.

Comment: Comedians make fart jokes. Humorists jest about breaking wind. Great comedians take a s--- on the stage.

Comment: Mark Twain was a humorist, not a comedian. A comedian is a performer. It might (or might not) help to know that *comedian* also means an actor in a comedy. And in French (from which English grabbed the word) a *comedian* is an actor (not necessarily in a comedy). A *comedy* in Ancient Greece was an amusing story of conflict.

Comment: A comedian is, amongst other things, a pejorative term for a clown or an idiot. "He's a right comedian" is commonly heard in gangster movies shortly before someone is shot.

Comment: Comedians do not write stuff except for their own performance material;  they say stuff and act out stuff.

Comment: Is everyone who writes something funny a humorist? I wouldn't use the word for some forms of funny writing (e.g. sitcom scripts, funny literary fiction, someone employed by a comedian to write one-liners) but might for others, e.g. newspaper columns, funny stories. What's the difference between a humorist and a joke-writer? Mark Twain is often called a humorist, but what about Joseph Heller, Dickens, Swift, or Pope?

Answer (score 2):

A humorist tells funny stories and a comedian tells jokes. A humorist's stories can include jokes, of course, and a comedian's jokes might need a bit of a story for setup. So it's a continuum, and  it's probably a waste to time to debate whether someone who falls somewhere mid-spectrum is a comedian or a humorist.

Comment: Although there seems a trend for comedians to use the term "humorist" ironically. And certain publications like The New Yorker use the term "humorist" a lot as part of their general old-fashioned style. So it's certainly not a hard-and-fast distinction.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that a humorist would be trying achieve something via their humour; for comedians the comedy itself is the goal. Therefore whilst we would find the cartoonist of a newspaper being described as a humourist, no-one would call Charles M. Schulz a comedian.

Comment: What was Peanuts trying to "achieve"? It's a wholesome comic that specifically avoided controversial topics. Compare this with the social commentary underlying many modern comedians' acts - I disagree that a comedians just want the laugh while humorists have a broader agenda.

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie Yes; the terms seem rather fuzzy at the edges. I'd not call a cartoonist or writer of comedy items a comedian per se, whether they were in it for the fun or tub-thumping. . But the Wikipedia article gives a stipulative definition, in which the comedian uses humour for humour's sake (and no doubt usually some cash) and the humourist uses humour as an oratorical (or literary) instrument. They can't both be the controlling factor, as there will be [A and ~B] examples (like Schulz).

Comment: I'd argue the opposite. Especially today, "humorist" is applied to people like Garrison Keiller or David Sedaris who focus on quirky stories with no purpose to them, while comedians are more likely to be discussing political issues (whether from the left or the right). I'd call Schulz a humorist but wouldn't call an editorial cartoonist like Ben Garrison a humorist or a comedian. Maybe you could actually research the use of the terms.